# hive table select sql column type exception

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

There is a hdfs parquet dataframe called gender.

```
gender = spark.read.parquet('/user/path/grass_date=2019-03-06')
```

after reading parquet, we get the schema:

```
DataFrame[userid: bigint, gender_scores: double, predicted_gender: bigint]
```

at last, we create hive table using this command:

```
CREATE TABLE gender_history
 USING org.apache.spark.sql.parquet
 OPTIONS (path='/user/path/grass_date=2019-03-06')
```

some people do select * command which throw below exception:

> gender_scores in file
>   hdfs://scluster/user/path/grass_date=2019-03-06/part-00008-c961a5f3-4126-45bf-8487-38b07377dbcb-c000.snappy.parquet
>   is declared as type **real** but parquet file declared column type as
>   **DOUBLE**.

I want to know what caused this issue and how should I fix it. Thanks all!

Comment: Try saving the table with `stored as parquet` instead of `USING org.apache.spark.sql.parquet`. Spark's parquet and Hive's parquet are not exactly the same formats.

Comment: @serge_k after using parquet can still support the sql？

Comment: @serge_k but it is the first time to get the issue. never have before even using org.apache.spark.sql.parquet